# How to write a scientific thesis

Tags: support, specific-question

I wonder if my question about scientific thesis writing is appropriate to ask.

Is there supported claim that a scientific thesis should not have many personal pronoun words e.g. we/you/our?

I would like to know advice if I should reduce the number of personal pronouns in my report. There was repetition in the text of too many "we", I think, e.g. "We have...We do/did....Our thesis..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this question would be fine here. Academic writing is firmly on-topic on Writers.